# LatticeReduce question

Tags: matrix, number-theory, lattices

Does `LatticeReduce` work with arbitrary precision arithmetic? That is, if I give it a linearly independent integer basis, but the integers are 40 decimal digits long and SVD says the largest singular value is 10^16 times larger than the smallest singular value, will it still give me a good LLL reduced basis?

Comment: Try it and see!

Comment: Yes and yes, in that order.

Comment: Of course, you need to indicate the precision of all the numbers you use in order for Mathematica to actually apply arbitrary precision arithmetic.